# Reactive Extensions, trigger OnNext immediately and then over an interval

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observable

I have a webservice that I want to query for updates immediately after a boolean is set to true, and then recheck every 5 minutes.

Here is my current observable:

```
        _queryDisposable = Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
            .ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)
            .Where(i => IsProcessing)     // IsProcessing is the bool value
            .Subscribe(GetFeeds, OnError, OnComplete);
```

This observable will check if the `IsProcessing` bool is true or false every 5 mins and then call `GetFeeds` if it is true.

The only way that I can think to get the desired effect is to make `IsProcessing` a property backed field and process with 2 observables like the following:

```
    private bool _isProcessing;

    public bool IsProcessing
    {
        get { return _isProcessing; }
        set
        {
            if (_isProcessing == value)
                return;

            _isProcessing = value;

            if (!value)
            {
                if(_queryDisposable != null)
                    _queryDisposable.Dispose();
                _queryDisposable = null;
            }
            else
            {
                Observable
                    .Range(0,1)
                    .ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)
                    .Subscribe(GetFeedsSafe, OnError, OnComplete);

                _queryDisposable = Observable
                    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
                    .ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)
                    .Subscribe(GetFeedsSafe, OnError, OnComplete);
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't think that is a very elegant solution, and so I'd like to know if there is a better way to acheive this effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am I missing something, or wouldn't you just call Subscribe yourself immediately before starting the Observable?

```
    Subscribe(GetFeeds, OnError, OnComplete);
    // Or perhaps, if you want it to be async,
    new TaskFactory().StartNew(()=>Subscribe(GetFeeds, OnError, OnComplete));

    _queryDisposable = Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
        .ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)
        .Where(i => IsProcessing)     // IsProcessing is the bool value
        .Subscribe(GetFeeds, OnError, OnComplete);
```

EDIT: Pure Rx, from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sa/rx/thread/c4acaf34-3136-4206-a6f9-ef5afba74b2b:

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
        .StartWith(-1L)
        .ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)
        .Where(i => IsProcessing)     // IsProcessing is the bool value
        .Subscribe(GetFeeds, OnError, OnComplete);
```

Comment: lol, valid point! I am trying to see if there is a pure Rx way to do something like "Fire, then fire on `TimeSpan` interval".

Comment: Standard practice is to put `ObserveOn` as the last operator before subscribing, unless one of the later operators must run on a specific scheduler.

Answer (score 3):

To start you sequence immediately and still produce a value in a given time you have two options:

1. Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)).StartWith(-1)
2. Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))

Next I assume that you want to cancel a timer when the IsProcessing value is set to false, you also want to restart the sequence when it is set back to true. The two answers above run a 5minute interval regardless of when the IsProcessing value is set. If you set IsProcessing=true, the sequence will start, if a minute later you set IsProcessing=false and then IsProcessing=true, you will still have to wait 4minutes before it queries again. I assume this is not what you want?

So we want this to be triggered off a property change. @SPFiredrake does a good job of suggesting INPC and turning the event into an Observable sequence. There are lots of little snippets around that help you do this. asuming we use one that is an Extension method PropertyChanges, we can write this pretty simple query.

```
var isProcessingValues = this.PropertyChanges(x=>x.IsProcessing);
isProcessingValues
    .Where(isProcessing=>isProcessing)
    .SelectMany(_=> 
        Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
                  .TakeUntil(isProcessingValues.Where(isProcessing=>!isProcessing))
    )
    .Select(_=>GetFeeds())  //What does GetFeeds actually return?
    .SubscribeOn(Scheduler.NewThread)
    .Subscribe(feedData=>Console.WriteLine(feedData), 
        ex=>Console.WriteLine (ex),
        ()=>Console.WriteLine (completed));
```

Slowly stepping through this:

1. When the IsProcessing property changes, push the new value into a sequence (isProcessingValues)
2. When a sequence value is true, start a timer sequence that produces a value now and every 5 minutes.
3. The timer sequence should stop if the isProcessingValues sequence produces a value of false
4. each time the timer ticks (when IsProcess is set to true and every 5 minutes while it is true), make a call to GetFeeds
5. ensure that our sequence is subscribed to on a different thread (to not block). Remove if this is not a requirement.
6. Take the data from the feed and do something with it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about making the IsProcessing variable fire a prop changed event that you can then listen to?

```
var processing = Observable
    .FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventArgs>(this, "PropertyChanged")
    .Where(tr => tr.EventArgs.Property == "IsProcessing" && ((Type)tr.Sender).IsProcessing);

_queryDisposable = Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
    .ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)
    .And(processing) // Will only fire when both sequences have an available value.
    .Subscribe(GetFeeds, OnError, OnComplete);
```

This also ensures that if it IS processing, it will only fire once as the processing observable only ever provides a single value at a time (for each IsProcessing changed to `true`) so you don't have to worry about it firing again if it's still processing 5 minutes later.